# error con Spring boot :Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled

Tags: spring-boot, apache, tomcat, puertos

Corro el proyecto y me sale este error, me dice que el puerto 8080 ya esta en uso pero ya detuve la ejecución con el pid, el puerto 8080 esta siendo usado por Tomcat. No entiendo que es lo que genero este error ya que antes arrancaba bien, ya intente cambiar de puerto, pero cuando lo hago y corro la aplicacion se detiene y no avanza.

```
      .   ____          _            __ _ _
     /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
    ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
     \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
      '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
     =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
     :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.5)

    2023-03-15 21:56:13.439  INFO 5804 --- [  restartedMain] c.P.jcaceres.JcaceresApplication         : Starting JcaceresApplication using Java 19.0.1 on DESKTOP-PGCDVOT with PID 5804 (C:\Users\54346\OneDrive\Escritorio\Mi Portfolio\ProyectoIntegrador\ArgProg_backend\jcaceres\target\classes started by 54346 in C:\Users\54346\OneDrive\Escritorio\Mi Portfolio\ProyectoIntegrador\ArgProg_backend\jcaceres)
    2023-03-15 21:56:13.448  INFO 5804 --- [  restartedMain] c.P.jcaceres.JcaceresApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
    2023-03-15 21:56:14.029  INFO 5804 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
    2023-03-15 21:56:14.030  INFO 5804 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
    2023-03-15 21:56:23.431  INFO 5804 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
    2023-03-15 21:56:25.827  INFO 5804 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 2262 ms. Found 3 JPA repository interfaces.
    2023-03-15 21:56:37.903  INFO 5804 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
    2023-03-15 21:56:38.017  INFO 5804 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
    2023-03-15 21:56:38.020  INFO 5804 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.68]
    2023-03-15 21:56:38.605  INFO 5804 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
    2023-03-15 21:56:38.606  INFO 5804 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 24569 ms
    2023-03-15 21:56:39.172  WARN 5804 --- [  restartedMain] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
    2023-03-15 21:56:39.880  INFO 5804 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
    2023-03-15 21:56:40.214  INFO 5804 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.12.Final
    2023-03-15 21:56:41.231  INFO 5804 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
    2023-03-15 21:56:41.949  INFO 5804 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
    2023-03-15 21:56:42.781  INFO 5804 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
    2023-03-15 21:56:42.869  INFO 5804 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
    2023-03-15 21:56:47.345  INFO 5804 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
    2023-03-15 21:56:47.387  INFO 5804 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
    2023-03-15 21:56:54.251  INFO 5804 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@79856e4a, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@74b3f17e, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@48acc1de, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@4f72c1c6, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@5a923572, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@6d50a9dc, com.Portfolio.jcaceres.Security.jwt.JwtTokenFilter@3a8c491d, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@76f3b588, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@553ea11a, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@520dd458, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@7f55a06d, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@63ec3e7a, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@5af1ef41]
    2023-03-15 21:56:55.771  INFO 5804 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
    2023-03-15 21:56:55.878  WARN 5804 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.PortInUseException: Port 8080 is already in use
    2023-03-15 21:56:55.895  INFO 5804 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
    2023-03-15 21:56:55.911  INFO 5804 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
    2023-03-15 21:56:55.959  INFO 5804 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
    2023-03-15 21:56:56.003  INFO 5804 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
    2023-03-15 21:56:56.148  INFO 5804 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

    Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
    2023-03-15 21:56:56.412 ERROR 5804 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

    ***************************
    APPLICATION FAILED TO START
    ***************************

    Description:

    Web server failed to start. Port 8080 was already in use.

    Action:

    Identify and stop the process that's listening on port 8080 or configure this application to listen on another port.

    Command execution failed.
    org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:982)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:929)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute (ExecMojo.java:457)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke (DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:578)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke (DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:578)
        at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start (BootstrapMainStarter.java:47)
        at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute (WrapperExecutor.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main (MavenWrapperMain.java:72)
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    BUILD FAILURE
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Total time:  01:15 min
    Finished at: 2023-03-15T21:56:57-03:00
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec (default-cli) on project jcaceres: Command execution failed.: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec (default-cli) on project jcaceres: Command execution failed.
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:375)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke (DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:578)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke (DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:578)
        at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start (BootstrapMainStarter.java:47)
        at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute (WrapperExecutor.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main (MavenWrapperMain.java:72)
    Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Command execution failed.
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute (ExecMojo.java:478)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke (DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:578)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke (DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:578)
        at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start (BootstrapMainStarter.java:47)
        at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute (WrapperExecutor.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main (MavenWrapperMain.java:72)
    Caused by: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:982)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:929)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute (ExecMojo.java:457)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke (DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:578)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke (DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:578)
        at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start (BootstrapMainStarter.java:47)
        at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute (WrapperExecutor.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main (MavenWrapperMain.java:72)


    For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

este es mi pom.xml tiene esta configuracion

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.portfolio</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcaceres</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>jcaceres</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.4</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.4</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.4</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Este es mi application.propierties. He mirado videos de youtube y tampoco dan ninguna solucion, verifique las respuesta anteriormente obtenida en esta web y tampoco me funcionan.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/backendjcaceres?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect


#JWT
jwt.secret = secret
jwt.expiration = 3600
```

---

aca esta mi application.propierties con el nuevo puerto

```
spring.port=8888
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/backendjcaceres?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect


#JWT
jwt.secret = secret
jwt.expiration = 3600
```

y me sigue dando el mismo error

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-03-16 13:27:55.705 ERROR 10564 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Web server failed to start. Port 8080 was already in use.

Action:

Identify and stop the process that's listening on port 8080 or configure this application to listen on another port.

------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
```

Cuando detengo la ejecucion de Tomcat en xampp que es el que usa el puerto 8080 la ejecucion de mi aplicacion queda tildada tal como la imagen

[image: Cuando detengo la ejecucion de Tomcat en xampp que es el que usa el puerto 8080 la ejecucion de mi aplicacion queda tildada tal como la imagen]

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: Por favor indica cómo le cambiaste el puerto a la aplicación (qué archivo modificaste y cómo). El problema puede ser de forma y no de fondo (el mensaje es claro y no es evidente que tu cambio haya surtido efecto; tampoco vimos si el mensaje de error cambió). Edita tu pregunta y añade la info adicional, por favor. Y procura no hacer adivinar a los lectores :)

Answer (score 0):

La causa del error está en las primeras líneas de la traza, es muy explícito si sabes inglés:

```
    ***************************
    APPLICATION FAILED TO START
    ***************************

    Description:

    Web server failed to start. Port 8080 was already in use.

    Action:

    Identify and stop the process that's listening on port 8080 or configure this application to listen on another port.
```

Traducción aproximada:

> Descripción
>
> El servidor web falló al iniciarse. El puerto 8080 estaba ya ocupado.
>
> Acción (para resolver el problema):
>
> Identifica y para el proceso que está escuchando en el puerto 8080 o
> configura esta aplicación para escuchar en otro puerto.

Y esa es la solución: elije otro puerto (en tu application.properties pon `spring.port=8888`, por ejemplo) o comprueba qué aplicación tienes levantada y está usando el puerto. En el peor de los casos, reiniciar el PC debería resolver el problema

Answer (score 0):

Es un error muy común en SpringBootToolSuite que no coja el application.properties correctamente, me pasó lo mismo que a ti, realiza estos pasos, y debería de funcionarte correctamente:

1. Ir al properties del proyecto que falla
   [image]
2. Nos vamos a Java Build Path → Source → nombreProyecto/src/main/resources
   IMPORTANTE: asegurate que sea el de la carpeta /resources
   [image]
3. Pinchamos donde pone Excluded: ** → Remove
   [image]
4. Se tiene que quedar en Excluded: (None)
   Apply, Apply And Close y así debería de funcionar.
   [image]

Sino usas SpringToolSuite, te recomiendo que te pases a este en vez de usar Netbeans.

Comment: Hola Dani!muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta!